maximum call stack size exceeded Angular Syncfusion charts
I was using Syncfusion SplineRange chart, initially I declared its 'dataSource' with the sample data like below
 <e-series
 [dataSource]="data"

when I get data from back-end, I am updating this.data = result.data, when I directly do this , I get call stack exceed message. Is there any way to update dataSource to make it work properly?

try this to run your server node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --configuration=local
where 8192 means 8GB

Tried, but same error.

what is a size of your result.data?

the size is 490KB but its not the size, because even I set ' this.data = []', I am getting same error, inside Syncfusion using a loop which is running infinity times for some reasons, that is why it is giving that error, So I need different approach to update the value
